# How are goals in football distributed?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, bayesian

So I'm trying to predict football (soccer) results, using mathematics.
I have already made a Poisson model, since at first glance it seems very appropriate; "The Poisson distribution is popular for modelling the number of times an event occurs in an interval of time or space".

I have found, when reading literature on the subject, that Poisson seems to be the route that people most often take. However I can't help but think that the Poisson isn't quite right.

Just for one reason, for the Poisson to be appropriate, we have to assume that goals are independent events. I'm sure anyone who watches football will agree with me when I say that it seems goals are not independent. It seems so frequent in football that a team scores a goal, and has some kind of impetus to quickly score another.

This leads me to believe that there is an element of Bayesian statistics here. That we should consider the probability of a goal, given that there has recently been a goal.

Getting to my question: Does anyone have any suggestions on how to modify a Poisson distribution to account for Bayes' theorem? Or even, does anyone know of a model that is more fitting to goals in football, than the Poisson model?

Comment: About the soccer reference: keep in mind that around 38% of football matches of major championships end with 1 goal or less in total or with 1-1 (source https://www.windrawwin.com/statistics/full-time-scores/ ), so there is a 38% of matches where this "impetus" doesn't hold. To this 38% you should add every match with a strong or weak alternance of goals between teams. Maybe the poisson distribution may fit better.

Comment: Hi - looked at this a few years back for fun. Basically as you know the mkt quotes home, away and draw odds. From these you can calibrate marginal $\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$ for your marginal goal arrival rates. However the acid test is replicating the correct score profile. There's a whole suite of models to help you fit / calibrate correlated event arrivals (eg simple credit derivatives models). Simplest tractable model - Just use a gaussian copula to impose dependency on arrival times and have a play around with the correlation. It's very interesting to see the calibrated correlations.

Comment: if get time will write an answer but when I looked at it worked very well against live quotes. A single correlation parameter with such a simple model reproduced with good success full correct score profile calibrated just from home/away/draw odds. But you are right, you need dependency, and a simple gaussian copula works / worked very well

Comment: (actually unless contracts have changed, I was calibrating marginals and correlation to 1) Home, 2) Away and 3) <2.5 goals prices. These then allow you to price, with the calibrated parameters, the odds of a 2-3 result say. If can find an old spreadsheet will write out what I did and how closely it fitted pricing across the goal 'capital structure'! On your dependency point, zero correlation will not in general fit the correlation dependent <2.5 goals mkt well at all.

Comment: (and finally the above won't directly answer your question as regards an explicit 'bayesian' framework, however obviously implicitly it does so by introducing dependency which is necessary).

Comment: @Mehness Is there any source material/link/ implementation to see what you mean with copulas? If not a good place to start learning about them?